# Python pip argparse upgrade

Tags: python, pip

I have been attempting to upgrade `argparse` on Ubuntu 16.04 to the latest version, but `pip` keeps saying that it is part of the standard library.

How can this package be upgraded?

```
$ sudo pip install argparse --upgrade
Collecting argparse
  Using cached argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: argparse
  Found existing installation: argparse 1.2.1
    Not uninstalling argparse at /usr/lib/python2.7, as it is in the standard library.
Successfully installed argparse-1.2.1
```

Thanks.

Comment: [It is part of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Argparse is maintained as a separate package here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse
Which is where pip is going to collect it.

But

> As of Python >= 2.7 and >= 3.2, the argparse module is maintained
>   within the Python standard library. For users who still need to
>   support Python < 2.7 or < 3.2, it is also provided as a separate
>   package....

So, you are getting the error because it *is* part of the standard library, but also available to install via pip if you are using a version of Python for which it *isn't*.

If you really need to install 1.4.0 try this: (worked for me on my Windows 2.7.11 install)

- Download the gzip file, not the wheel, from the pypi [downloads](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse#downloads) page
- Uncompress the archive and open a terminal in the `argparse-1.4.01` folder
- Run `python setup.py install` (See the 'Install' section of first link)

And check you now have the correct version (hopefully):

```
>>> import argparse
>>> argparse.__version__
'1.4.0'
```

**Note:**
This still leaves the original `argparse.py` (in `...Python27\Lib` for me) intact, and places the 1.4.0 egg in `site-packages`, with an `easy-install.pth` file which I presume ensures that this version gets used in preference to the standard library one.